# Accessing sprites in a NSMutableArray returns an error - simple question

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Why doesn't this work?

```
// spriteArray is an NSMutableArray
int spriteWidth = [spriteArray objectAtIndex:0].contentSize.width;
```

I get the error:

Request for memeber 'contentSize' in something not a structure or union

If I change the code:

```
CCSprite *tempSprite = [spriteArray objectAtIndex:0];
int spriteWidth = tempSprite.contentSize.width;
```

Then it's okay.

I've tried casting:

```
int spriteWidth = (CCSprite*)[spriteArray objectAtIndex:0].contentSize.width;
```

But it doesn't work either.

Is there a way to do this without creating the sprite reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return type of `objectAtIndex:` is `id`, which is not a `struct` nor `union`. If you want to use casting, try

```
((CCSprite*)[spriteArray objectAtIndex:0]).contentSize.width
```

Otherwise, use a temporary variable.

Comment: Yes, that's works.

I had tried placing the cast in different positions, but I didn't try the one above.

Any recommendations for learning more about casting?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the `.` binds tighter than casting. Try

```
int spriteWidth = ((CCSprite*)[spriteArray objectAtIndex:0]).contentSize.width;
```

See [this table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence).

Comment: dreamlax beat you to it.

Thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: I beat him by about 12 seconds, but that's ok. To see why you need to do it this way, see the table I linked to. The accessor `.` has higher precedence than casting, so the compiler tries that before changing types. To override this, you can use parentheses.

Comment: Have an upvote! It's only worth two thirds of an accept, but still!

Comment: Thanks, I don't mind. I'm building up my score rather steadily. You can have one too.